# What am I doing that is causing the indices to be drawn out of order

Tags: javascript, webgl

I have a buffer for:
position, using Float32 values.
color, using Uint8 values. 
indice, using Uint32 values.

all of the arrays used to create the buffers are completely fine. Infact, I am using this [isoSurface mesher](http://mikolalysenko.github.io/Isosurface//) by Mikola Lysenko I am using. I am using webGL instead of threeJS, but the outputs of the mesher match his threeJS geometry object exactly when supplied with the same data.

So, I know there is a simple mistake I am making. I actually have fixed this before, but my computer crashed and the file corrupted and now I am running into it again. I forgot what I did to fix it. Here is all the relevant code.

Creating the VAO

```
gl.bindVertexArray(sector[sectorID].vao);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,sector[sectorID].buffers.position);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(
   programInfoCube.attribLocations.voxelPosition,3,gl.FLOAT,false,0,0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(programInfoCube.attribLocations.voxelPosition);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, sector[sectorID].buffers.color);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(
   programInfoCube.attribLocations.voxelColor,3,gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,false,0,0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(programInfoCube.attribLocations.voxelColor);
```

Updating the VAO (these are all of the correct data types as far as the typed arrays go, and with the correct data)

```
sector[sectorID].buffers.size=indOffset*2;
//Bind this sector VAO
gl.bindVertexArray(sector[sectorID].vao);
//Set data
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sector[sectorID].buffers.indice);
gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,sectorIndiceBuffer,gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW,0,indOffset);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, sector[sectorID].buffers.position);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,sectorPositionBuffer,gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW,0,posOffset);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, sector[sectorID].buffers.color);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,sectorColorBuffer,gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW,0,colOffset);
```

and finally drawing it at render time

```
gl.drawElements(
    gl.TRIANGLES, sector[drawList[i][0]].buffers.size,gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT,0);
```

The result of this with this code is, all of the indices get messed up. and they always seem to point towards the same spot so it creates giant triangles all pointing to the same spot.

Thanks

Comment: You claim you're using Uint32 values for indices but your draw call is using `gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT`.  Also your `bufferData` calls the last variables are call `xxxOffset` which might be correct but the last argument to `bufferData` is a length. Of course maybe that's correct for your code, just pointing it out in case.

Comment: There we go thanks. Sorry, stupid mistake from not being used to typed values . May I ask what value you would use for u32int values as indices? If you can?

Comment: @SebastianFrederick *"what value you would use for u32int values as indices"*: `gl.UNSIGNED_INT`